# How to change bootstrap columns width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

how to expand top panels (marked as red) so as to be over the entire width of the page (marked as green)?
All must have the same width.

And second and similiar problem.
I need to add 7th table at the bootom. How to do it, so they all have the same width?

[image]

Online demo: [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Up72aWXutI)

My code is here:

```
<div class="container-full">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 column well">
            <h2>
                Heading
            </h2>
            <p>
                Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 column">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                                        Panel title
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Panel content
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    Panel footer
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 column">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-2 column">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    #
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Product
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Payment Taken
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Default
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Approved
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>
                                    2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    02/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Declined
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="warning">
                                <td>
                                    3
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    03/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Pending
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="danger">
                                <td>
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    04/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Call in to confirm
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 column">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    #
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Product
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Payment Taken
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Default
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Approved
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>
                                    2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    02/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Declined
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="warning">
                                <td>
                                    3
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    03/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Pending
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="danger">
                                <td>
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    04/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Call in to confirm
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 column">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    #
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Product
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Payment Taken
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Default
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Approved
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>
                                    2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    02/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Declined
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="warning">
                                <td>
                                    3
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    03/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Pending
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="danger">
                                <td>
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    04/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Call in to confirm
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 column">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    #
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Product
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Payment Taken
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Default
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Approved
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>
                                    2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    02/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Declined
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="warning">
                                <td>
                                    3
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    03/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Pending
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="danger">
                                <td>
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    04/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Call in to confirm
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 column">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    #
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Product
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Payment Taken
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Default
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Approved
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>
                                    2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    02/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Declined
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="warning">
                                <td>
                                    3
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    03/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Pending
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="danger">
                                <td>
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    04/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Call in to confirm
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 column">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    #
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Product
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Payment Taken
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Status
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Default
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    01/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Approved
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>
                                    2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    02/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Declined
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="warning">
                                <td>
                                    3
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    03/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Pending
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="danger">
                                <td>
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    TB - Monthly
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    04/04/2012
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Call in to confirm
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have 9 col-md-1 columns it is impossible since they cant be divided by 12 (grid system has 12 parts).

However, you can have 3 col-md-4 additional wrappers and put 3 col-md-4 columns inside each and that should give you the result you ask for.

Something similar to this:

```
 <div class="container-full">
         <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-3 column well">
        <h2>
            Heading
        </h2>
        <p>
            Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
        </p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 column">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...content...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...content...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...content...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...content...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...content...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...content...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...content...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...content...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...content...
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Fixed spelling mistake to wrapper col-md-3 => col-md-4

Answer (score 6):

I've had to do this on RARE occasion...but when necessary, it can help...but anyway, you can create a custom grid definition so you could have a 7 column grid:

```
<div class='row grid7'>
    <div class='col-md-1'>1/7th</div>
    <div class='col-md-1'>1/7th</div>
    <div class='col-md-1'>1/7th</div>
    <div class='col-md-1'>1/7th</div>
    <div class='col-md-1'>1/7th</div>
    <div class='col-md-1'>1/7th</div>
    <div class='col-md-1'>1/7th</div>
</div>
```

Then, some CSS to make it work:

```
.grid7 .col-md-1 { width: 14.285714285714%; }
.grid7 .col-md-2 { width: 28.571428571429%; }
.grid7 .col-md-3 { width: 42.857142857143%; }
.grid7 .col-md-4 { width: 57.142857142857%; }
.grid7 .col-md-5 { width: 71.428571428571%; }
.grid7 .col-md-6 { width: 85.714285714286%; }
.grid7 .col-md-7 { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help 
https://github.com/drew-r/bootstrap-n-column
you can create n-column bootstrap layouts using LESS

Answer (score 2):

You can use **col-fluid** instead in bootstrap then with css specifying its width

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-fluid sidebar">
           <a href="#">log in</a>
           <a href="#">sign up</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar{
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    min-height: 100vmin;
    width: 200px;
}
```